# Suitable search backend for standalone mail archive

Tags: email, solr, lucene, full-text-search, archive

Since I couldn't find a suitable existing application to archive my e-mail, i want to build one myself. Up to now, I used MailStore Home, but it runs only on Windows and packs many mails in one db file. Lately, some files got corrupted and I lost a big load of mails instead just a few.

Basically, I want the mail to be backed up as standalone files (eml, msg), one per mail, and organized in folders on the hard drive. That's the easy part. Now I'm looking for a search backend to index & search the mail-files. I want to access it via webpage or build an QT App around it.

Requirements: Run standalone on PC (Notebook, desktop PC, whatever), run on Linux and Windows, reasonable hardware requirements, quick start & shutdown.

I looked into Lucene and Solr and they seem to provide all the features I need & seem to be resonably easy to integrate. Still, I'm not sure wheather they are suitable for standalone running and being restartet every time I open and close the application, or if there are other tools better suited for such a use.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Solr is a great component of the email archive. You can run it embedded if you want and the rest of your backend is Java, though running it as a standalone service is preferred.

Given that it is archives and will not change, you may specifically look at the [collection aliasing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) which will allow to do one search across multiple underlying cores. That would mean you could have a core per week or per month or per export. This is a common solution for logs, which are also accumulated one way.